# Making a span editable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make two spans editable, when clicking a button.
Can someone please tell me, why this isn't working?

Here's the fiddle, and the code:

[JSFIffle](http://jsfiddle.net/D6Wft/11/)

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Title1</th>
<th>Title2</th>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td><div style="border: 2px solid black;" id="2" contenteditable=false> Text1 </div></td>
<td><div style="border: 2px solid red;" id="3" contenteditable=false> Text2 </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="edit_properties">Edit</button>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$('#edit_properties').on('click', function() {
$("#2").attr('contenteditable', true);
$("#3").attr('contenteditable', true);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine once you *add jQuery* to the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D6Wft/12/  (small cog icon in the js panel)

Comment: @AlexK. could you please take a look at this one? I want to change to an input box when click the button edit. here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2D9FW/173/